# Julia parametric subtyping "<:" operator equivalent for declaring the parametric type

Tags: generics, julia, parametric-polymorphism

This is me probably going off what is considered idiomatic in Julia, as I am clearly abusing parametric types (generic types instead of hardcoded ones) but I am struggling to understand why this doesn't work and what are my alternatives.

Say we have this parametric type `{T}`:

```
struct mystruct{T}
    val::T
end
```

I can restrict the possibilities by supertyping `T`:

```
struct mystruct{T<:Number}
    val::T
end
```

But I don't seem able to restrict it to a certain type:

```
struct mystruct{T::Int64}
    val::T
end
```

My goal is being able to declare several fields at once by declaring the generic struct with `Int64` as I did above. So I'm looking for the `<:` equivalent.

My end goal is to do this:

```
struct mystruct{T::Int64}
    val::T
    max::T
    mystruct(val::T) = begin
    new(val, typemax(T))
    end
end
```

Instead of what I currently do:

```
struct mystruct
    val::Int64
    max::Int64
    mystruct(val::Int64) = begin
    new(val, typemax(val)) # or typemax(Int64)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This sounds a bit like a solution in search of a problem—ultimately, doesn't your issue boil down to `Int64` being too long to type?

If so, you could just define a type alias

```
const T = Int64
```

at the top of your code.

If `T` is different every time, you could use a `let` block like this:

```
julia> let T = Int64
           struct MyStruct
               a::T
               b::T
               c::T
           end
       end

julia> MyStruct(4, 5, 6)
MyStruct(4, 5, 6)
```

Then `T` is no longer in scope, which is probably what you want:

```
julia> T
ERROR: UndefVarError: T not defined
```

Finally, although I can't see a reason for it, you can also have a parametric struct whose parametric type is just `Int64`: `struct MyStruct{Int64} a::Int64 end`.

And note that `T::Int64` and `T<:Int64` aren't really analogous in the sense that `t == 5` and `t <= 5` are. The visual similarity is misleading: In `T<:Int64`, `T` is a *type* that is a subtype of `Int64`, whereas in `T::Int64`, `T` is a *value* of type `Int64`. To keep yourself on the right track, you should make sure that whatever you write before `::` is in lowercase, which customarily denotes a value rather than a type.

Comment: Ah ah! A SISP in the wild. Actually it's not cause I had the problem first, but my solution suggestion might be the weird thing. I did not think about declaring it a variable, I love that even more!

Comment: What are the implications of parameterising here `struct MyStruct{Int64} a::Int64 end`? I don't see how it's different from just having `a::Int64`, but I'd like a pointer to understand it. I tried to do `struct MyStruct{Int64} a end` but it just doesn't work.

Comment: `struct MyStruct{Int64} a end` with proper line breaks works, although I can't get it to show in a comment. This is simply a type with only one field, namely `a`, that can take values of any type. The `{Int64}` bit is superfluous, and really only serves to make it harder to create instances of the type: `MyStruct(4)` errors whereas `MyStruct{Int64}(4)` works.

Comment: ah, that's it, Julia doesn't care about linebreaks I just didn't know I had to do `MyStruct{Int64}(4.5)`. That also answers my question,`a` has nothing to do with the type parametrization. I'm sure there's a use case for this construct though.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see much utility in restricting parametric types to one type, but you can do so by restricting the type in your internal constructor:

```
julia> struct mystruct{T}
           val::T
           max::T
           mystruct(v::T) where T <: Int64 = new{T}(v, typemax(v))
       end

julia> mystruct(4)
mystruct{Int64}(4, 9223372036854775807)

julia> mystruct(n) = mystruct(Int64(n))
mystruct

julia> mystruct(Int32(5))
mystruct{Int64}(5, 9223372036854775807)
```

Comment: Uh a new construct! But how's this different from declaring `mystruct(v::Int64) = new{typeof(v)}(...)`? I had to use `typeof` because for some reason I don't currently understand, `T` is given as not defined.

Comment: See the discussion on Parametric Composite Types above. Honestly, the simplest way is to drop the parameterization and just make mystruct.v and mystruct.max to be declared to be Int64.

Comment: If you really want to keep the restriction in the parameter for struct, this also works: struct mystruct{T <: Int64};
    val::T;
    max::T;
    mystruct(v::T) where T = new{T}(v, typemax(v));
end;  # (you need the `where T` in the function to make sure T is in scope for new)

Answer (score 1):

As you can read in the section on [Parametric Composite Types](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/types/#man-parametric-composite-types) of the Julia manual and the following section Julia allows you to define types that have parameters. Such types have names `Type{TypeParameters}`.

Note that, on purpose I concentrate only on type name not on whole type definition as it is irrelevant. What is important to understand here that the whole construct `Type{TypeParameters}` defines a type, i.e. the `{TypeParameters}` part is part of the type. Here is an example:

```
julia> struct Type{Int}
       end

julia> t = Type{Int}()
Type{Int64}()

julia> typeof(t)
Type{Int64}
```

Note that type parameter, in general does not have to be associated with fields of a composite type:

```
julia> struct Type1{T<:Int}
           val
       end

julia> Type1{Int}("a")
Type1{Int64}("a")

julia> Type1{Union{}}("b")
Type1{Union{}}("b")
```

The parameters of a type are just a way to bundle together multiple types sharing some common structure and functionality.

Now note:

```
julia> struct Type2{T<:Int}
           v::T
           Type2{T}() where {T} = new()
       end

julia> Type2{Int}()
Type2{Int64}(1609504000)

julia> Type2{Union{}}()
Type2{Union{}}(#undef)

julia> Type2{Any}()
ERROR: TypeError: in Type2, in T, expected T<:Int64, got Type{Any}
```

Here I used incomplete initialization to actually create an instance of `Type2{Union{}}` type that has a field of type `Union{}` although it is impossible to properly initialize it.

See:

```
julia> x = Type2{Union{}}()
Type2{Union{}}(#undef)

julia> fieldtypes(typeof(x))
(Union{},)
```

I additionally run `Type2{Any}()` constructor to show you that the type restriction of `struct` is enforced.

In summary - in general type parameter is just a part of the type name. Then when defining types writing `Type{<:SomeType}` is just Julia analogue of covariant type. Just as `Type{>:SomeType}` is analogue of contravariant type. See [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/types/#Parametric-Abstract-Types) for an explanation. Also maybe discussion of [`UnionAll` types](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/types/#UnionAll-Types) might be helpful for you to understand this topic.

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed that `subtypes(Int64)` returns nothing so in my case `{T<:Int64}` already does what I wanted.

For types which are not at the end of their hierarchy, an `abstract type` such as `Signed`, it wouldn't make sense to do what I am asking:
`{T::Signed}`

So it's a non issue.

Comment: `Union{} <: Int64` is a difference. It might be relevant in some cases (not in this though).

Comment: What is that exactly?

Comment: I mean that when you use subtyping with `<:` you potentially allow `Union{}` type. This is sometimes problematic with multiple dispatch. In your case it is not a problem as `Union{}` type has no values of this type. Here is a brief example with an empty collection `Union{}[] isa Vector{<:Int64}` produces `true`.

Comment: AH I understand now! Thanks!! Pardon to ask, but how is my case immune to that?

Comment: Also what values could be of type `Union{}`? Can't think of any

Comment: No values can have `Union{}` type and that is why your case is immune, because your struct is immutable and has some elements. E.g. `struct SomeStruct{<:Int64} end` (without any element) would not be immune to this problem.

Comment: That actually takes me to one of my questions above. What is the `<:Int64` doing there then?

Comment: I will add an answer as it seems more explanation is needed.